# How can I put the folder containing my iCloud documents in the Finder sidebar?

Tags: finder, icloud, macos

iCloud documents live in `~Library/Mobile Documents`. But if I try to drag said folder to the Finder sidebar, I get a "do not enter" sign, and it won't add. How can I put my iCloud documents folder in the Finder Sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make an alias to the `~/Library/Mobile Documents` folder. Then, drag the alias to the sidebar.[image]

Comment: But by using an alias, it won't let me access sub-folders when I try to save!

Comment: I don't have the tools for it, but is this a sym link? Its permissions are fine, should allow. Notice how you can't do a normal Get Info?

Comment: Just notice, you *can* add it to Finder menu bar.